# Asp.net: handle null in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, null, linq-to-xml

in a ASP.NET application (MVC) I have a foreach loop that loops through a structure that may contain or not some element:

```
        <% foreach (XElement segnalazione in ((XElement)ViewData["collezioneSegnalazioni"]).Elements("dossier")) { %>

            <tr>

                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("NUM_DOSSIER").Value) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("ANAG_RAGSOC_CGN").Value) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("ID_RIFATT_SEGN0").Value) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("FLG_STATUS").Value) %></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("DT_ACCADIMENTO").Value)%></td>
                <td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("COD_RAMO_LUNA").Value) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
```

Now, I get a NullReferenceException when Element("DT_ACCADIMENTO") is not set within the XElement. Is there a quick way to handle this? I tried with

```
<td><%= Html.Encode(segnalazione.Element("DT_ACCADIMENTO").Value ?? "")%></td>
```

but it does not work as, I guess, it checks if *Value* is null, where I have a problem with the field itself.
Any help appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td><%= Html.Encode((string)segnalazione.Element("DT_ACCADIMENTO") ?? "")%></td>
```

Comment: Explicit Operator for XElement to string cast (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
segnalazione.Element("NUM_DOSSIER") == null ? "" : segnalazione.Element("NUM_DOSSIER").Value
```

Comment: You'd be querying the XElement object twice, which might harm performance in case there's a lot of child elements, and I don't think it has any advantage over the plain approach in LINQ to XML. Don't you think?

Comment: You're absolutely right and I think your solution is better. Not sure why I'm getting all the votes ;-)

Comment: Mehrdad's solution doesn't encode the Value property.  Does the Element output it's Value property when the toString is called?  If not then I would think that would be an incorrect implementation.

Comment: @Joseph: The cast will return null if the element is `null` and Value if it's not null. `ToString` is irrelevant here. It's using an explicit operator string(XElement) that's defined for XElement.

Comment: @Mehrdad Oh I see.  Very cool! +1 I didn't notice the explicit operators (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx)

Comment: In fact, these operators are the standard methods in LINQ to XML (specially in `where` clauses). Without them the queries will be pretty ugly.